# Fruit colour related to the dissolving of pectin

Tags: cell-biology

What does the dissolving of pectin have to do with the colour of a fruit?

Answer (score 3):

During ripening, pectinases are produced which break down pectin and render it soluble. Color change is also associated with fruit ripening.

Hence the correlation.

Comment: So there is a correlation but no causation?

Comment: yes as it seems. Both are an effect of ripening. Chloroplasts differentiate and lose chlorophyll and other metabolic changes cause pectin hydrolysis along with other things such as increase in sugar content etc.